# Div gets added automatically for a sharepoint note field (multiple lines of text)

Tags: 2013, 2010, solution-package, rich-text

I have two  columns of note type, `GreetingMessage` and `PopupMessage`

I have built ascx pages to save and edit it

When I save it, I attached to the process and checked the data,

For both the columns the value is sent as **test**

Even in the list the value is saved as **test**

But when I get the item using id, it returns

```
"<div class=\"ExternalClass09B743SDFKJH435JK34\">test</div>"
```

as the value for the first field

I checked both the fields, they both have the same setting and `Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)` is selected in both columns

Comment: This is the expected behavior for enhanced rich text fields

Comment: But this is happening only in one of the enhanced rich text fields?

Comment: Are you saving the two fields in the same way?

Comment: Yeah, exactly the same way
I even checked what's being saved and both save same data
But, when I do a getItemById it returns value with this div

Comment: I changed both to plain text, changed them back to rich text and now getting the same issue in both the fields ! Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

Keep column as plain text. In this case not getting additional div tags.

Specify the type of text to allow: 
    Plain text   <<<<
    Rich text (Bold, italics, text alignment, hyperlinks)
    Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)